# Django Choice Field options not showing

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using a choice field to allow users to be assigned to different tickets, but when choices are given, they don't appear on the webpage.

**forms.py**

```
class TicketAssignedForm(forms.Form):

def __init__(self, ticket, *args, **kwargs):

    print(ticket.assignable())

    super(TicketAssignedForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.choices = {
        "assigned": ticket.assignable()
    }
    print(self.choices['assigned'])
    self.initial = {
        "assigned": ticket.assigned,
    }

assigned = forms.ChoiceField(label="Assigned")
```

The print statements both output:

```
[<User: Bob>, <User: Jim>, <User: Jeff>]
```

this being a list of User objects.

**views.py**

```
ticket_assigned_form = TicketAssignedForm(ticket)
return render(request, 'view_ticket.html', {'ticket_assigned_form': ticket_assigned_form})
```

In theory I should have a select input with an option for each of the users, but instead it's just empty.

**Edit**

I've also tried to use the following list however I get the same result:

```
[(1, 'Bob'), (2, 'Jim'), (4, 'Jeff')]
```

Comment: Choices expects a list (iterable) of 2-tuples with a key and value, not a list of `User` objects. You might want to look to a `ModelChoiceField`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Is that not only for querysets? I would use it, however I am changing the original queryset.

Comment: yes that is for querysets. I however don't see what `ticket.assignable()` should return a list? Normally it is better to use querysets over lists, since these are lazy, and filtered at the database side, so often more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choices expects a list (iterable) of 2-tuples with a key and value, not a list of `User` objects. You might want to look to a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField). In that case however the `ticket.assignable` should be a `QuerySet`, not a list.

You can not alter the `self.choices`, but the choices of that specific field:

```
class TicketAssignedForm(forms.Form):
    
    assigned = forms.ChoiceField(label='Assigned')

    def __init__(self, ticket, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['assigned'].choices = [(i, str(u)) for i, u in enumerate(ticket.assignable())]
        self.fields['assigned'].initial = ticket.assigned
```

Comment: The problem I have with using `ModelChoiceField` is that in ticket.assignable, I get all the users in the database and then loop through them to check if they have permissions to be assigned. Ideally, I'd end up doing this: `User.objects.all().has_permission()` but obiously that won't work.

Comment: @UnknownPerson: well you can look if you can filter it, like `User.objects.filter(...)`.

Comment: @UnknownPerson: Since Django-3.0, you can filter with `with_perm`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.with_perm